# Sequence difference equatiom

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations

For $n \ge 2$ the terms in the sequence
$a = \{1, 6, 17, 45, 118, 309, \ldots\}$ are related by the difference equation

$$a_{n+2} = \boxed{\phantom{XX}} \, a_{n+1} + \boxed{\phantom{XX}} \, a_n $$

The values are positive or negative integers.

Can anyone help me with the equation please. 
appreciated

Comment: nice editing Alex

Comment: @Omnitic thanks, my initial incentive was only to change the tag ;D

Comment: obviously 3 and -1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Our recurrence relation is of the form $a_{n+2} = x a_{n+1} + y a_n$, and we would like to determine $x$ and $y$. For $n=1$, we get the equation $17 = 6x+y$, and for $n=2$, we get $45 = 17x+6y$. We now solve this linear system.

Comment: $\large\left\{1,6,17,45,9087,23897,7865\right\}$, for example, yields the same answer.

Comment: @FelixMarin No, your sequence does not satisfy any recurrence relation of second degree.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: A quick eyeball estimate says that each term is very roughly three times the previous term, so do a little arithmetic:

$$\begin{array}{rcc}
n:&0&1&2&3&4&5\\
a_n:&1&6&17&45&118&309\\
3a_{n-1}:&-&-&18&51&135&354\\
a_n-3a_{n-1}:&-&-&?&?&?&?
\end{array}$$

**Added:** There are of course mechanical solutions, but it’s also useful to be able to spot patterns.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$a_{n + 2} = xa_{n + 1} + ya_{n}$.
$$
\!\!\!\!{\cal F}\pars{x,y}
\equiv
\half\bracks{%
\pars{x + 6y - 17}^{2} + \pars{6x + 17y - 45}^{2} + \pars{17x + 45y - 118}^{2} +\pars{45x + 118y - 309}^{2}}
$$
Minimize ${\cal F}\pars{x,y}$ respect $x$ and $y$. If the minimum of ${\cal F}\pars{x,y}$ is $\large\tt zero$, then the values of $x$ and $y$ you found are the right ones $\pars{~\mbox{it assumes}\ x\ \mbox{and}\ y\ \mbox{are}\ n-\mbox{independents}~}$.

That procedure [yields the global minimum](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x+%2B+6y+-+17%29%5E2+%2B+%286x+%2B+17y+-+45%29%5E2+%2B+%2817x+%2B+45y+-+118%29%5E2+%2B+%2845x+%2B+118y+-+309%29%5E2) ${\cal F}\pars{x, y} = 0$ at $\color{#0000ff}{\large x = -1,\quad y = 3}$.

Then
$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
a_{n + 2} = -a_{n + 1} + 3a_{n}}
$$

Comment: Though it will work, this is a lot of work.  At the very least, you can use only two of the parenthesized terms.

Comment: @RossMillikan With, for example, $\large\left\{1,6,17,45,90765,-7869,-5678\right\}$ yields the same values if we check $1,6,17,45$. In any case, we have to check that the next values can be find with the same parameters. In my procedure, we are pretty sure that's the answer since the global minimum is zero.